# CLion doesn't pick up environment variables sourced in bashrc

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc, sh, clion

### Long Story (This is X)

> I need to start [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) with `sudo` so that I can attach `gdb` to the running process from CLion (for a debugging purpose). The reason is because when I run CLion *without* `sudo`, and trying to attach to a process (CLion GUI), I receive:
>  
>  `com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver$GDBCommandException: ptrace: Operation not permitted.`
>  
>  As a second check, I tried running `gdb` in the terminal manually without `sudo`:
>  
>  `gdb -p 16741`
>  
>  `...`
>  
>  `Could not attach to process. If your uid matches the uid of the target process, check the setting of "/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope", or try again as the root user. For more details, see "/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf"`
>  
>  `ptrace: Operation not permitted.`
>  
>  **However**, if I run `gdb` with `sudo`:
>  
>  `sudo gdb -p 16714`
>  
>  `...`
>  
>  `Attaching to process 16714`
>  
>  So I think I should run CLion as root.

---

### TLDR / The Problem (This is Y)

Now, *if* running `sh /opt/clion/bin/clion.sh` from the Ubuntu terminal, CLion *does* pick up the environment variables sourced in the `~/.bashrc` file, and my program compiles with no error.

But because without `sudo`, I can't attach `gdb` to the process from within `CLion` for my debugging purpose, so I need to run the `clion.sh` startup script as root.

**The problem is that** when running `sudo sh /opt/clion/bin/clion.sh`, CLion *doesn't* seem to pick up the environment variables, leading to "CMake cannot find package ..." error, which makes my program not runnable⁠—worse.

```bsh
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:64 (message):
  find_package(catkin) failed.  catkin was neither found in the workspace nor
  in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.  One reason may be that no ROS setup.sh was
  sourced before.
```

## Question

How do I run the CLion startup script with `sudo`, and preserve the environment variables that are sourced in `~/.bashrc`?

---

### If relevant

- I think CLion doesn't pick up the following variables. To be very specific, I have this line in my `~/.bashrc` file:

  ```bsh
  source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
  ```

  whose content is

  ```bsh
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  # generated from catkin/cmake/templates/setup.bash.in

  CATKIN_SHELL=bash

  # source setup.sh from same directory as this file
  _CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(builtin cd "`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`" > 
  /dev/null && pwd)
  . "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"
  ```

  Perhaps, there might be a way to add this directly to the startup script of CLion?
- [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
- I am running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I'll need more coffee before I really understand what you're asking but a couple of observations: (1) `sudo` performs an `env_reset` by default - only preserving a minimal environment (2) `sh` is not `bash` (at least, not by default) and in any case, `.bashrc` is only sourced for interactive shells. Fundamentally, I think this likely *is* an XY problem - see for example [How to solve “ptrace operation not permitted” when trying to attach GDB to a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32274645)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for pointing those out to me. I agree that this is likely an XY problem; because I could go with fixing the X, which is `ptrace operation not permitted` when attaching `gdb` to the process problem. And if that solved the problem, I wouldn't need to ask the Y, which is about dealing with `sudo`, environment variables, `sh`, `~/.bashrc`, etc.

Comment: There are similar questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171339/gdb-cannot-attach-to-process), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662130/clion-or-cmake-does-not-see-environment-variable), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215177/how-to-solve-ptrace-operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-attach-gdb-to-a-pro/46676868), but none of them directly answer the question (the Y) that I asked here.

Comment: The only workaround that works for me is to look into the `~/.bashrc` file and set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` in CLion accordingly, by pointing this variable to the folder that contains the missing packages. Also set the variables as outlined by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662130/clion-or-cmake-does-not-see-environment-variable). However, `~/.bashrc` is something that I change frequently, so I'm not sure if this is the best way to go.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that you should fix your kernel parameters so that you don't need to run the IDE with `sudo` - in which case, it will inherit its parent environment (including things like `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, so long as they have been exported) in the usual way

Comment: @steeldriver, I came back to accept your comment as an answer. Modifying `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` as in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215177/how-to-solve-ptrace-operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-attach-gdb-to-a-pro/32274645#32274645) that you posted does solve the problem *indirectly*. By modifying this file, I can now attach to a process within CLion without having to run CLion as root (and as usual, running CLion from terminal does pick up the environment variables).

Answer (score 1):

I came back to accept @steeldriver 's comment as an answer.

Modifying `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` as in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215177/how-to-solve-ptrace-operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-attach-gdb-to-a-pro/32274645#32274645) in his comment does solve the problem *indirectly*.

That is, by modifying this file (changing from `1` to `0`), I can now run GDB attach to a process within CLion without having to run CLion as root. And as usual, running CLion from terminal does pick up the environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Source your variables in `.profile` not `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and got the same problem. My solution is to create another script `clion-with-env.sh` that setup all the environment variables

```bash
#!/bin/bash
source setup-vars.sh
source setup-vars2.sh
export MYVAR=...
...
sh /foo/bar/clion-*/bin/clion.sh
```

Then modify the application file e.g. `/usr/share/applications/jetbrains-clion.desktop`, change the `Exec` option to `Exec="/path/to/clion-with-env.sh"`. This is the file that creates the CLion icon in your launcher. You might need to wait a few seconds or logout to update the settings.

If you want to print something in `clion-with-env.sh` to debug, you can change the `Terminal` option to `true`. Then a terminal will show before CLion starts.

I first tried to use `source /home/user/.bashrc`, but somehow it didn't work.